# jQuery: keydown event fires multiply times

Tags: jquery

At present, when I press the Ctrl button and hold it pressed for a while, the handler that I binded to the keydown event with the help of jQuery is triggered multiply times - I would like to avoid triggering it more than once per a separate press. How would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 3):

If, whatever you are doing, does not have to be triggered immediately, you could listen to [`keyup` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) instead.

Otherwise, you could set a flag on `keydown` and clear it on `keyup`:

```
$element.keydown(function() {
    var data = $(this).data();

    if(!data['pressed']) {
        data['pressed'] = true;
        // do stuff
    }
}).keyup(function() {
    $(this).data('pressed', false);
});
```